# Similarity between Java and C code

Tags: c

My task is to count how many distinct words I have in a file using C. I already did the same assignment in Java but I have some difficulties doing this in C. I've read a lot about pointers and arrays and how to initialize them in the constructor but I still don't get it, that's why I'm asking for help.

This is how I do it in Java:

```
public class DataSet {

private String[] elements;
private int top;

public DataSet() {
    elements = new String[1];
    top = 0;
}
```

And now I'm trying to do the same thing in C and this is how my code looks like:

I have two classes the first one DataSet.h:

```
typedef struct _DataSet {
    char *elements;
    int top;
} DataSet;
```

and the second one DataSet.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "DataSet.h"   /*external libaray */

DataSet* createDataSet() 
{
  DataSet* d = malloc(sizeof(TextString));
  d -> elements = malloc(1 * sizeof(char));
  d -> top = 0;
  return d;
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. are my understanding correct: I create an object DataSet in order to be able use the variables, then I set the pointer to this new array called elements which might contain one string, then I set the top to 0 and in the end i return the object.
2. if it's not correct what should I do in order to make it exactly the same as my Java code?

Comment: You probably want an array of `char*` or a pointer to `char*` which would then be allocated an array

Comment: I'm too tired to say anything useful except that it's unnecessary and slightly bad style to multiply by `sizeof(char)`; it's always 1 by spec. Good for not casting the return from `malloc`.

Comment: What is `TextString`? C doesn't have classes.

Comment: Removing the `[java]` tag as the answer won't be about Java.

Comment: I want to make string array as i did  in java, but i`m not sure that this is the correct way to do it in C. I`ve read a lot of explanations how to make String Array in C and in all of them, they use the word char instead of String (because there is no possibility to use the word String in C as a data type)

Comment: The Java implementation can only hold one `String` and the C implementation can only hold one `char` (which would only be enough for the terminating `\0` that a string in c needs to have).

Comment: @chrylis you're correct but you seem to have overlooked that while he's using `char` as the type size for malloc, his code shows that his intention is to store character strings (so he needs to malloc `char *` elements, and then potentially allocate further space for each one). Also, I disagree that `sizeof(char)` is bad style except to say `sizeof(some_variable)` is better; hard coded values that make no immediate sense are much worse for readability.

Answer (score 2):

Generally if you are `malloc`ing a struct like `DataSet`, you should make sure that the size of the allocation is the same as the size of the struct.

Your line

```
DataSet* d = malloc(sizeof(TextString));
```

Is definitely wrong, but may work by accident if TextString is bigger than DataSet. You really should write:

```
DataSet* d = malloc(sizeof(DataSet));
```

If you want to store an array of strings like you do in Java code, the type is wrong in this line of the DataSet struct:

```
char *elements;
```

Remember that in C, a string is an array of characters. So an array of strings is an array of arrays of characters, like this:

```
char **elements;
```

Also, you do not want to allocate space for one character, as you do in the line

```
d -> elements = malloc(1 * sizeof(char));
```

Rather you want to allocate space for a pointer to a character (the first one in the string).

```
d -> elements = malloc(1 * sizeof(char *));
```

Note that this does not allocate any memory for the characters themselves!

Comment: Your `elements` malloc is incorrect. The pointer is in the struct, so you don't need to allocate it. You do, however, need to allocate space for the characters, and you're right that 1 probably isn't enough.

Comment: Almost, the Java class has an array of strings, I've added a bit about the struct not having the right type of `elements`

Comment: I've removed the downvote :) I'll add an upvote if you add a bit about writing `sizeof(d->elements[0])` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you want to allocate memory for a DataSet struct, so this is :

```
DataSet* d = malloc(sizeof(struct _DataSet));
```

--

```
d -> elements = malloc(1 * sizeof(char));
```

here you just allocate memory for one char, I think you need memory for a string :

```
d -> elements = malloc(n * sizeof(char)); // where n is the max length of your string
```

hope this helps

Comment: Yes i need a memory for a string. Thank you very much for the responses.

Comment: Also note that `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, by the C standard.